# how to load .RData file whose names contains a previously save system date in R

Tags: r, date, save

Assume I save my data ( say mtcars ) as .RData with this name format:

```
save(mtcars, file = paste0("data","_",Sys.Date(),".RData"))
```

this file `data_2022-05-26`.RData and many more files with similar name construction are saved in my documents now.

my problem is if in future time I want to load this or any of these files, how can I do it?

```
load(paste0("data","_",Sys.Date(),".RData"))
```

what I exactly what is to save `Sys.Date()` somehow when creating the file name, so that I can use it instead of `Sys.Date()` which makes `load()` function to look for a file with today's date.

edit. I must point out that I have to create my .rda file and load it later either same day or another day, but the codes are both in the same r file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you have the file on two different dates, you'll have two different files in there. Something like `data_2022-05-25.RData` and `data_2022-05-26.RData`. If you run the code again on 2022-05-27, which file should it open? Do you always want to open the most recent? `Sys.Date()` will always be the current date on your computer.

Comment: I save data_2022-05-25.RData today. how to save the date this file was created originally, put in a variable say myvar. and later when I run the code including making a new file and loading the file made on date a I can use load(paste0("data","_",a,".RData"))? my problem is a <- Sys.Date() changes a each time but I want it saved.

Comment: You can do `rundate <- Sys.Date()` and then `save(mtcars, file = paste0("data","_",rundate,".RData"))` Then the `rundate` variable will have that same date. You save that however you like, and then use `load(paste0("data","_",rundate,".RData"))` when you want to load it again. you can save the value of `Sys.Date()` just like any other value in R.

Comment: what is the difference between calling a variable a or rundate?

Comment: A variable value only changes when you explicitly set a new value. A function returns a value. That value may be the same or different each time you run it, but once that value is returned from the function, it will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all file names, parse out the date, then pick the most recent one.

```
library(tidyverse)
list_of_files <- dir() # use this in real life
list_of_files <- c("data_2022-05-25.RData"," data_2022-05-26.RData") # for demonstration only

most_recent_date <- str_match(list_of_files, "data_(.*)\\.RData")[,2] %>% 
    lubridate::ymd() %>% 
    max()

paste0("data","_",most_recent_date,".RData")
# load(paste0("data","_",most_recent_date,".RData"))
```